# Are CosmosDB attachments (still) a good way to store payloads larger than the document limit of 2MB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I need to save CosmosDB documents that contain a large list - larger than the document limit of 2 MB. 
I'd like to split that list into an 'attachment' associated to the "main document".

But [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits) briefly mentions that

> Attachment feature is being depreciated [sic]

What's the deprecation plan? Will newly created collections (in the future) stop supporting attachments?

The same page of documentation mentions a limit of 2GB for "Maximum attachment size per Account".

What does that mean? 2GB per attachment? 2 GB total for all attachments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend not taking a dependency on attachments. We are still planning on deprecating them but have not started in earnest on this.

Depending on your access patterns for this data you may want to break this up as individual documents or modeled in some other way. CRUD operations on large documents can be very costly and will experience high latency because of the large payload in each request.

If you have an unbounded array these should definitely be stored as individual documents or modeled such that increasing size does not cause eventual performance issues. If your data is updated frequently it should be modeled such that the frequently updated portions are separate from properties that are static.

This article here describes scenarios and considerations when modeling data in Cosmos and may help you come up with a more efficient model. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data

Hope this is helpful.